# Include File causing Error 500 in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Maybe this is a bonehead question, but I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I have to make an update to an old, classic ASP web site.  One of the requests was to modify the footer so that the comments and suggestions could have the emails associated with a link changed in the administration panel.

That's not the problem, the original footer used on all pages was added as...

```
</div>
<!--#include file="../include/footer.htm"-->
</body>
```

If I add enter code here

`enter code here`<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>

to the top of the page and change the extension to either .inc or .asp, modify the original page to:

```
</div>
<!--#include file="../include/footer.inc"--> (or .asp)
</body>
```

...I get an Error 500.  I've tried using the web console in the browser, but no additional info there and there is no code on the page, only the declaration that VBScript will be used.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sure this is something stupid that I knew 15 years ago, but just can't remember since I haven't touched ASP since 2002.

Comment: It was indeed a bonehead mistake.  As John pointed out below and I figured it out at the about the same time, you don't want to put a script declaration into an include file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parent paths are disabled by default in iis 7.  This means that you'll get an error if you use "../" in an include file path

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-parent-paths-are-disabled-by-default

You could enable them in iis manager or you could use include virtual

```
<!--#include virtual="/root/include/footer.htm"-->
```

You could also use iis manager to edit how the server handles error pages, so that you can get helpful debug text rather than just a 500 internal server error page

Comment: Parent paths were already enabled.  There is no issue when using the original code where the file is named .htm.  The error occurs after adding the vbscript declaration and changing the extension to .asp or .inc

Comment: What happens if you lose the vbscript declaration but keep the .asp extension?

Comment: When you use an include file statement what you are doing is telling the server to copy and paste the text of the include file into your asp script before the script is run.  Having a vbscript declaration in your include is therefore like having the declaration in the middle of your script.

Comment: Hi John....I was coming back to the page here to update that apparently the VBSCRIPT declaration was causing the issue.  I wish you'd have stumbled by here about 6 hours ago, but I still thank you.

Comment: I am marking your answer as correct since you at least offered something that someone might try and then actually nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

first check IIS configuration

ERROR 500 causes by web server, google can found about this

Comment: I know you are trying to help, but this is a useless answer.

Comment: Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you set it as an .asp or .inc page then I recommend you set the content of the page up like this:

```
<%
'code here
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you include B.asp into A.asp: also check that: B.asp not contains global variables / functions that are already declared in A.asp